# ESX Server 5.1 - Consolidation Error : Locked file

Tags: vmware-esx, consolidation

I try to consolidate a virtual machine that needs consolidation but I get the message:

```
Consolidate virtual machine disk files
Servername.mydomain.internal
Unable to access file 
<unspecified filename> since 
it is locked
Administrator
XXXXXX.mydomain.internal
15/4/2015 12:07:05 μμ
15/4/2015 12:07:05 μμ
15/4/2015 12:07:48 μμ
```

I tried to migrate to another server, rebooted also precious host. It is difficult to migrate 1Tb to another datastore. how can I find the locked file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reboot (one after the other) all three physical servers and guess what: The third one had a lock on one of the files!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly same situation but maybe this VMWare KB article helps little - http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=10051

And usually, if nothing else helps then power off and clone VM and then use cloned VM.